# WYSIWYG editor resources and ASP.NET MVC project folders structure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tinymce, ckeditor, wysiwyg

Is there a fast way to move all the images and CSS from plug-ins' (like CKEditor or TinyMCE) folder to corresponding folders in the ASP.NET MVC projects' folders?
Maybe there are "out-of-the-box" or automated solutions Or the only way is to edit all the paths to the new ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NuGet](http://nuget.org/) is a Visual Studio extension that makes it easy to add, remove, and update libraries and tools in Visual Studio projects that use the .NET Framework.

When you use NuGet to install a package, it copies the library files to your solution and automatically updates your project (add references, change config files, etc). If you remove a package, NuGet reverses whatever changes it made so that no clutter is left.

You can install new packages using the [package manager console](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/using-the-package-manager-console).

[TinyMCE Package](http://www.nuget.org/List/Packages/TinyMCE)

[CKEditor Package](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/CKEditor)

Comment: That's a wrong answer. I've tried to install CKEditor and it was just copied into Scripts folder. And I want to put styles into Content folder and images into Images folder.

Comment: @drunkcamel MVC by default comes with `Content` and `Scripts` (there is no `Images` folder). `Content` is the recommended location for static files and `Scripts` for script files. However, this is only a recommendation, so each packet NuGet may apply its own rules. Some packages (i.e. jQuery UI) put CSSs and images on `Content`, some other packages don't. The main advantage of using NuGet is that you do not have to manually install and update all your plugins. If you want to keep your folder structure, then you will have to edit all paths manually.